# How do I run an anonymous function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, anonymous-function

I am using Angular 2's http.post to send some data and retrieve the results.  Once I get the results back, I'd like to run a function, but it appears that anonymous functions don't work.  How do I accomplish this?

Snippet:

```
this.http.post("/login/login", this.model)
    .subscribe(res => function () {
        console.log('a', this.res);
    },
    error => function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    },
    () => function () { 
        console.log("3"); 
    } );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous functions should work with typescript.
Your syntax for arrow functions is wrong thought.
try removing the function keyword https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

Just try removing the word function

```
this.http.post("/login/login", this.model)
.subscribe(res => () {
    console.log('a', this.res);
});
```